# Создание функции SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, функции

Есть таблица `Туры` с полями:

- `ID_тура`
- `Страна`,
- `Город`,
- `Отель`,
- `Количество_звезд`,
- `Длительность`,
- `Цена_для_взрослых`,
- `Цена_для_детей`,
- `Цена_для_младенцев`.

Также есть другая таблица `Путевки` с полями:

- `ID_путевки`,
- `Количество_взрослых`,
- `Количество_детей`,
- `Количество_младенцев`,
- `Стоимость` - **нужно вычислить**.

Необходимо получить доступ к данным из таблицы `Туры`.

Т.е. в таблице `путевки` есть поле `стоимость` которая должна быть вычисляемым столбцом. Расчет по формуле : `(@Количество_взрослых * Туры.Цена_для_взрослых)+ (@Количество_детей * Туры.Цена_для_детей)+(@Количество_младенцев * Туры.Цена_для_младенцев)`

Написал функцию, но получаю ошибку связанную с неправильным синтаксисом около SELECT

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue(@Количество_взрослых INT, 
                             @Количество_детей INT,
                             @Количество_младенцев INT)
    RETURNS MONEY
    AS
      SELECT (@Количество_взрослых * Туры.Цена_для_взрослых) + 
             (@Количество_детей * Туры.Цена_для_детей) +
             (@Количество_младенцев * Туры.Цена_для_младенцев)
      FROM dbo.Туры ;


 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Путевки(
  ID_путевки INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Количество_взрослых INT NOT NULL,
  Количество_детей INT NOT NULL,
  Количество_младенцев INT NOT NULL,
  Стоимость AS dbo.GetValue(Количество_взрослых, 
                            Количество_детей, 
                            Количество_младенцев)
  PRIMARY KEY(ID_путевки)
);
```

Comment: Укажите СУБД и ее версию

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER 18

Comment: Эта версия не существует. Существующие версии: 2019, 2017, 2016, 2014 и др. Вы можете получить это следующей командой: `SELECT @@ VERSION;`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19041: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Несколько наблюдений:

- Это скалярная функция, но в таблице может быть много строк. Вот
  почему мне пришлось добавить `TOP (1)`. Это вопрос для вашей логики. Я не уверен, что это правильно.
- Оператор RETURN отсутствовал.

**SQL**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue(@Количество_взрослых INT, 
                             @Количество_детей INT,
                             @Количество_младенцев INT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP(1) (@Количество_взрослых * Туры.Цена_для_взрослых) + 
            (@Количество_детей * Туры.Цена_для_детей) +
            (@Количество_младенцев * Туры.Цена_для_младенцев)
    FROM dbo.Туры);
END
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Но Появилась ошибка что CREATE FUNCTION должна быть единственной в пакете. Я окружил функцию GO-ми и все работает отлично

Comment: Рад слышать, что сейчас все работает. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить мой ответ как «Ответ».

Comment: Появилась другая сложность. В таблицу Пуетвки я добавил столбец ID_тура, т.к. для разных туров цена разная. Но когда вычисляю используя данную функцию у меня считает данные только из первой строки таблицы Туры. Я поменял SELECT TOP(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Туры), но ничего не поменялось. А также иногда возникают проблемы с производительностью, вписываю данные, счетчик в первичном ключе остается в положении NULL, данные расчетов появляются после закрытия таблицы и повторном ее открытии.

Comment: Как я объяснил ранее, с функцией есть логическая проблема. Она должна использовать одну единственную запись, и непонятно, какую именно. Может быть, еще один параметр будет полезен.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за отзывчивость. Учел ваш комментарий и добавил параметр @ID_тура, а в условии задал WHERE @ID_тура=Туры.ID_тура . Работает превосходно

Comment: @AzizjonKhatamov, Пожалуйста, свяжитесь со мной в LinkedIn.

Comment: не пользуюсь LinkedIn